# ios core data persistence during applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, core-data, persistence, didreceivememorywarning

I added a managedObjectContext save to my applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning method in the app delegate.  The app seems to crash on some devices when I receive a memory warning now.

It seems that the save pushes the app over the memory limit, as it is already low.

The reason I have this save in that method is to catch anything that may not have been saved during normal app operation.

Can someone tell me if this is bad practice?

Thanks.